# Is Karplus-Strong synthesis a reliable way to test pitch detection algorithms?

Tags: matlab, pitch, hardware

I'm using Arduino DUE (Cortex-M3 based board).

I want to make a guitar sound using DAC (digital to analog converter).

For instance, the note A2's fundamental frequency is 110 Hz (using A4 440 Hz as the standard).
As you know, guitar generates harmonics like 220, 330, 440 Hz, and more.
More complex, the amplitudes of each sine waves change as time goes by.

This is described with detail at [this paper (Figure 1, Electric & Acoustic Guitar Strings: A Recording of Harmonic Content by Ryan Lee)](https://courses.physics.illinois.edu/phys406/student_projects/fall02/rlee/ryan_lee_p398emi_main_report.pdf)

I'm trying to understand the Karplus–Strong string synthesis.

(I used Matlab and some [examples from Mathworks](http://mathworks.com/help/signal/examples/generating-guitar-chords-using-the-karplus-strong-algorithm.html) to understand it.)

However, I'm not sure whether using this algorithm will generate a guitar sound like the acoustic guitar.

What I mean is that, I'm trying to test my pitch detection algorithm with a guitar. But taking a guitar all the time for testing is quite bothersome.
So I tried to generate a wave using DAC for faster testing.

**When using DAC, will the generated waveform which uses Karplus–Strong algorithm be a reliable input for testing a instrument pitch detection algorithm?**

**Or is there something else that can be used?**

Comment: Karplus-Strong is a synthesis algorithm.  you tell it the pitch and it produces a note.  it's not a pitch detection algorithm.

Comment: Why do you not simply take real guitar recordings to test your algorithm?

Comment: Just use real guitar recordings.  Put some on a smartphone and bring a cable?

Comment: Thanks for your reply (both  Jazzmaniac, endolith). I was concerned whether the recorded signal would be similar to the waveform vibration from the guitar's body.

I forgot to mention that I'm testing at an embedded system level. I'm using Cortex-M0 and 3 processors to do the pitch detection.

The Matlab codes were a reference for my test.

Due to these reasons, I wanted to connect thd Arduino's DAC output to my test board (the one doing pitch detection)'s ADC.

Comment: @robert bristow-johnson, thanks. What I meant was, I wanted to create a guitar waveform using Karplus-Strong, not to detect a pitch with this.

Using Arduino DUE and Karplus-Strong algorithm, do you think it is possible to synthesis a guitar note?

Comment: @DavidLee Close enough. Do note that people may put the tuner after a load of distortion and so on, in which case the tuner algorithm should be capable of working with any roughly harmonic sound.